# Can the qgis print composer memory limitation be overridden?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I'm trying to export large images from the QGIS 2.16.3 print composer. As far as I can tell, whenever the calculation of dpi and export size exceeds ~1615MB, QGIS will show the message:

> "Trying to create image #1( 21239x25360 @ 317dpi ) may result in a
>   memory overflow. Please try a lower resolution or a smaller paper size"

And then not attempt the export. The same limitation appears to be applied when trying to do the export from the command line as well.

Is this a standard limitation, or is it based on system specs? (I have 32GB of system RAM). Is there is a way to override it and make QGIS attempt to output the image?

Comment: This thread mentions using 64-bit build of QGIS to provide higher export resolution. http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/153464/35779

Comment: Thanks for that thread. Using 'file QGIS' command on the qgis app reports i'm using 'Mach-0 64-bit executable x86_64', so that shouldn't be the problem.