# High resolution geopdfs in Qgis 3

Tags: qgis, resolution, geopdf

In Qgis 2 I used to get high resolution geopdfs form the Georefexport plugin. In Qgis 3 i can get geopdfs by using the print composer/layout. However, I can not find a way to get high resolution geopdfs of many megabytes, so that when zooming into the geopdf, there is a lot of map detail, or "depth". How can I export high resolution geopdfs using the GUI in Qgis 3? Im on Qgis 3.4.2.

Comment: Does [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/3718/81764) answer your question?